# A Problem in DataGridView : datagridview seems readonly to user (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have a datagridview in my form. It fills by selecting country with cities of country.I have set the property (AllowUsersToAddRow = True)
but when i run my project user can't add or edit or delete any row.I checked it.It is not readonly(readonly = false) and It is enable (Enabled = true)

What's the problem?

Code of fill datagridview:

```
private void cmbCountryValues_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvCityValues.Enabled = cmbCountryValues.SelectedIndex>=0;
    if (!dgvCityValues.Enabled)
    {
        dgvCityValues.DataSource = null;
        return;
    }

    int CountryId = int.Parse(cmbCountryValues.SelectedValue.ToString());

    dgvValues.DataSource = from record in Program.dal.Cities(CountryId) select new { record.City};
 }
```

If you find this question useful don't forgot to vote it.

Comment: I removed the datagridview and created new one but the problem exist yet!!! :( :( :(

Comment: Is this winforms? webforms? Wpf? Silverlight?

Comment: In winforms............................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a simplified example, if I do the equivalent of your query, such as:

```
var cities = new City[] { new City("New York","NY"), new City("Sydney","SY"), new City("London","LN") };
dataGridView.DataSource = cities;
```

I get the same result as you - no option to add new rows, but if I change to `BindingList<T>` and set this to `AllowNew` it all works:

```
var cities = new City[] { new City("New York","NY"), new City("Sydney","SY"), new City("London","LN") };
var citiesBinding = new BindingList<City>(cities);
citiesBinding.AllowNew = true;

dataGridView.DataSource = citiesBinding;
```

EDIT - with a solution for your particular example:

```
private class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void cmbCountryValues_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvCityValues.Enabled = cmbCountryValues.SelectedIndex >= 0;
    if (!dgvCityValues.Enabled)
    {
        dgvCityValues.DataSource = null;
        return;
    }

    int CountryId = int.Parse(cmbCountryValues.SelectedValue.ToString());

    var queryResults = from record in Program.dal.Cities(CountryId) select new City { Name = record.City };
    var queryBinding = new BindingList<City>(queryResults.ToList());
    queryBinding.AllowNew = true;

    dgvValues.DataSource = queryBinding;
}
```

Note that a) I had to change the anonymous type in the query select into a concrete type `City` and also change the `IEnumerable<T>` returned by Linq query to an `IList<T>` compatible type to create the `BindingList<T>`. This should work, however :)

Comment: How can i convert it to bindinglist ? `var query= from record in Program.dal.Cities(CountryId) select new { record.City};`

Comment: Oh it works!! sorry bro your solution works.I have declared City  class with public field.When i changed it , and used the property,the problem solved. :) :) **Thanks so much**